# How Grunt or Gulp will trigger with MSBuild in a mvc application for minification?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, performance, gruntjs, gulp

I am not getting any example how to use grunt or Gulp in a mvc project for minfication, my requirement is if grunt does the minifcation of js and css file from the project folders and how the bundle.config will ensure to take those minified file during release mode?

Comment: Grunt / Gulp do not work in conjunction with asp.net bundling. You would just set up your bundle.config to handle bundling and minification for you. In MVC 5 .net bundling is replaced by gulp.

Comment: @MikeSheehan, I want to use grunt for minification of .net mvc applicaiton, how can i trigger grunt task with my msbuild where i have configured CI with MSBuild for my MVC Application.

Comment: @MikeSheehan What is the best way to do minfication of app folder script files in a mvc application and do you have any sample document to describe the steps?

Comment: You can trigger a grunt task by adding the command to a build event in visual studio: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ke5z92ks.aspx

Comment: If all you want to do with grunt is minification I would just stick to the built in bundling/minification in .net.